# How do I validate a tinyMCE editor, if it is blank by appending a string next to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, validation

I need to validate a form. This form has some dropdowns and tinyMCE editor, I am validating this form by appending the string "Required" after each field if it is blank, However I am unable to validate the tinyMCE editor, if the editor is blank,  I tried something like

```
tinyMCE.get('tinyedotor').getContent();
```

but no luck.

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S6Eqq/42/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`getContent()` should work just fine. Your fiddle doesn't contain the form validation code for the editor value, which is quite crucial here. Try this:

```
var editorContent = tinyMCE.get('tinyeditor').getContent();
if (editorContent == '')
{
    // Editor empty
}
else
{
    // Editor contains a value
}
```

[Forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvNMc/1/)

Also note you've declared multiple `id`'s for your `select` drop-down.

**Edit:** You can get the `id` of the editor container with the `getContainer()` method: `tinyMCE.get('tinyeditor').getContainer()`. Inserting an error message after the editor would then be something like this:

```
$('<span class="error">Editor empty</span>').insertAfter($(tinyMCE.get('tinyeditor').getContainer()));
```

This, however, will create a new `span` each time the user clicks the submit button, so you'll probably want to have an error message container with a unique `id` and check if the container already exists before inserting it.

**Edit 2**: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvNMc/15/).

Comment: @Victor: Great, I can do that but my problem is putting this string next to tinyMCE. I dont know how do I get the class / id of tinymCe, so I could do something like $(".errormrssage").appendTo('class/id of tinyMCEEditor');

Comment: @Victor: I added this code but looks like something more is needed for removing the message here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bvNMc/13/

Comment: @Victor: Is it possible to add this error message just next to tinyMCE and not at the bottom

Comment: @Thariama: Is it possible to add this error message just next to tinyMCE and not at the bottom

Comment: @Mike: sure, have a look at my answer with the link to the modified fiddle

Comment: @Mike: Yes, that's just a question of layout (HTML + CSS).

Comment: @Victor: thanks a lot for your help on this. Can we just put the message next to editor.

Comment: @Mike: Can you post the code for the `div` layout you mentioned? In the fiddle the fields are separated by line breaks, without any surrounding `div`s.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this to check if the content is empty without parsing html:

```
var content = tinymce.get('tinymceEditor').getContent({format: 'text'});
if($.trim(content) == '')
{
   // editor is empty ...
}
```

Comment: Very useful, because if there are some white spaces, in html format it doesn't count as empty any more.

Comment: It will be more useful, when you remove format filtering `{format: 'text'}`, because sometime user don't write anything but insert file/image.

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be easily done. Her is a [link to a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjbAq/) with my solution.

Comment: editor message empty has to be in line with the top line of tinyMCE editor, right now it is at the center. I can use position absolute and use top and left dimensions, but that will disturb, as my page has 3 tinymce editors and only one is shown based on some logic. Can we have this editor message on the first line in alignment with tinyMCE box.

Comment: @Mike: Align table cell contents for the table cell containing the error message: `<td style="vertical-align: top;">`.

Comment: @Viktor: but i have a div layout.

Comment: @Mike: Please post the code for your `div`-based layout if you want help improving it. Although I don't think this is related to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the getcontent() is the proper way, but what if user enters the space !!??
Here is the complete solution with the RegEX -

```
var content = tinyMCE.get('tinyeditor').getContent(), patt;

//Here goes the RegEx
patt = /^<p>(&nbsp;\s)+(&nbsp;)+<\/p>$/g;

if (content == '' || patt.test(content)) {
    $('.bgcolor').css("border", "1px solid Red")
    return false;
} else {
    $('.bgcolor').removeAttr("style");
    return true;
}
```

**Note:** ('.bgcolor') is nothing but a div around the 'tinyeditor' to have the red border when validation occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but with tinyMCE V4
Following worked for me.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#editorHtml'
});


    function IsCreatePostValid() {
    
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();

        if ($('#editorHtml').val().trim().length <= 0) {
            return false;
        }    
        return true;
    }
```

where #editorHtml is a text area, and on triggerSave MCE is populating the current rich text editor value to respective textarea.

so I am checking the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

`getContent()` is the way to go. You could just use the `tinyMCE.activeEditor` object and call `getContent()` on that or get the editor instance by id, like you're doing.

It looks like you've got a typo in your id, which is probably causing your issue.

```
tinyMCE.get('tinyedotor').getContent();
```

should probably be:

```
tinyMCE.get('tinyeditor').getContent();
```

Comment: it was just typo here in question, but my code is correct, did u check the fiddle

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see any `getContent` calls, only a `setContent` invocation. Am I looking at the right code? Also, it's currently throwing an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`