# Validating TinyMCE for empty inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I use TinyMCE as a very effective WYSIWYG editor.

There are no problems with the editor functionally. The problem comes when trying to determine if its empty.

---

### Problem

I need to validate the input of the TinyMCE textarea to ensure that something has been entered before I submit the form.

### What I have tried

I have discovered on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749179/how-do-i-validate-a-tinymce-editor-if-it-is-blank-by-appending-a-string-next-to) question that users have had success with this using the following statement

```
var editorContent = tinyMCE.get('tinyeditor').getContent();
if (editorContent == '')
{
    // Editor empty
}
```

For me there is a problem with this because instead of returning an empty string, the string returned looks like this (While empty):

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<head>↵</head>↵<body>↵↵</body>↵</html>"
```

I even tried evaluating the string like this

```
if (editorContent == "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<head>↵</head>↵<body>↵↵</body>↵</html>")
{
    // Editor empty
}
```

But it doesnt pick it up

### Code so far

```
function validateForm()
{
    var editorContent = tinyMCE.get('editor').getContent();
    if (editorContent == "" || editorContent == null)
    {
        // Add error message if not already present
        if (!$('#editor-error-message').length)
        {
            $('<span id="editor-error-message">Editor empty</span>').insertAfter($(tinyMCE.get('editor').getContainer()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Remove error message
        if ($('#editor-error-message'))
            $('#editor-error-message').remove();

        document.getElementById('submit').submit();
    }
}
```

Has something changed in TinyMCE? What am i missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because tinyMCE uses an IFRAME you may always get the inner text with:

`$('#tinyeditor_ifr').contents().find('body')[0].innerHTML`

or

`$('#tinyeditor_ifr').contents().find('body').text()`

So to check if the content is null you may check if:

```
$('#tinyeditor_ifr').contents().find('body').text().trim().length == 0
```

In the following the  code I used to test:

```js
$(function () {
  tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    mode: "textareas",
    plugins: "fullpage"
  });

  $('#btn').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log($('#tinyeditor_ifr').contents().find('body')[0].innerHTML);
    // this will output: "<p>This is <strong>my text</strong> that I <strong>use</strong> for my example.</p>↵"


    console.log(tinyMCE.get('tinyeditor').getContent());
    // this will output: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<head>↵</head>↵<body>↵<p>This is <strong>my text</strong> that I <strong>use</strong> for my example.</p>↵</body>↵</html>"
  })
});
```

```css
.textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.myButton {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/plugins/fullpage/plugin.js"></script>


<textarea id="tinyeditor" name="content" style="width:100%">
  &lt;p&gt;This is &lt;strong&gt;my text&lt;/strong&gt; that I &lt;strong&gt;use&lt;/strong&gt; for my example.&lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>
<button id="btn" class="myButton">Get TinyMCE Texr</button>
```

Comment: I solved this myself but because your answer allows a user to check if TinyMCE is empty even using the fullpage plugin i selected as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved it.

The problem was that I had used the FullPage plugin which automatically encodes the page as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and adds base html for a page.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/fullpage/

The code given in the question actually works just fine as the editorContent  string now returns empty or "" as expected

Answer (score 1):

what if user enters the space !!??
Here is the complete solution with the RegEX -

```
var content = tinyMCE.get('tinyeditor').getContent(), patt;

            //Here goes the RegEx
            patt = /^<p>(&nbsp;\s)+(&nbsp;)+<\/p>$/g;

            if (content == '' || patt.test(content)) {
                $('.bgcolor').css("border", "1px solid Red")
            }
            else {
                $('.bgcolor').removeAttr("style")
                return true;
            }
```

**Note:** ('.bgcolor') is nothing but a div around the 'tinyeditor' to have the red border when validation occurs.

Comment: Almost year passed from answer, but I faced with same issue.
This answer pretty close to cover all cases but it dont.

So I did few tests and improved this solution

/^(<p>(&nbsp;(\s)*)+<\/p>(\s)*)+$/g.test(content.trim())

this regexp in addition to regular check if empty (content != ' ') will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I found this worked for me:

```
var editorContent = '';
if(ed.getContent({format:'text'}).trim().length){
  editorContent = ed.getContent({format : 'raw'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following work for me with

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#editorHtml'
});


    function IsCreatePostValid() {
    
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();

        if ($('#editorHtml').val().trim().length <= 0) {
            return false;
        }    
        return true;
    }
```

[check the description : MCE V4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68409963/2683759)